# Passing custom arguments to jest

Tags: jestjs

Our client needs to run the entire test battery with a simple command, but he also needs to be able to change environments with a parameter.
Currently we run:

```
jest
```

And it runs all the files, which is good. We need something like:

```
 jest --env=local
 jest --env=dev
 jest --env=qa
```

Is this possible in any way?
The test files should be the same, all the testing works the same, we only need to run it on different urls

I've tried to parse the commands on my own, but jest won't let me. If I enter something different than the predefined commands, it fails with:

```
● Unrecognized CLI Parameter:

  Unrecognized option "a". Did you mean "$0"?

  CLI Options Documentation:
  https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html
```

I saw that I can add my own environments. I've tried with:

jest --env=qa

...to see its output and it prints:

```
● Validation Error:

  Test environment qa cannot be found. Make sure the testEnvironment configuration option points to an existing node module.

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html
```

But when I try to change those options I'm really lost. I can't seem to find something easy like

```
dev = {
    url = 'devUrl';
}
qa = {
    url = 'qaUrl';
}
etc.
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Would using environment variables work? `JEST_ENV=qa jest` and `JEST_ENV=local jest`. That way you can check for `process.env.JEST_ENV` when the tests are running

Comment: Yes, that works just fine. I've solved it differently though. I used the --setupFiles option from Jest, and a config file for each environment. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 4):

I followed the following steps and worked for me. Hope this will guide you as well

Requrement
 * Parse username and password as command line parameters
Script

```
"scripts": {
"loginTest": "jest tests/Login.test.js"
}
```

Steps
 * In js file I added below to read command line arguments

```
exports.USER_NAME = require("minimist")(process.argv.slice(2))["username"];
```

But to work above method I had to update the script as follows

```
"scripts": {
"loginTest": "jest tests/Login.test.js --username=test@test.com",
}
```

Then I found below method to parse argument into the script.

```
npm run loginTest -- --username=test@test.com
```

With this, I was able to achieve my requirement without changing the script

Comment: did you not get an "Unrecognized option" error from jest? i'm getting that doing something similar

Answer (score 2):

The following commandline and parsing can set environment/stage urls etc.

```sh
jest path/to/test.js '-stage=test'
# or...
npm test path/to/test.js -- -stage=test
```

```js
// test.js
const stageArg = process.argv.filter((x) => x.startsWith('-stage='))[0]
const stage = stageArg ? stageArg.split('=')[1] : 'dev' // default
const apiUrl = stage === 'prod' ? 'https://api.mysite.com' : `https://api.${stage}.mysite.com`
const request = supertest(apiUrl)
// ...etc...
```

Not that you should be running tests on prod, but it can be handy for things such as pull data monitoring, eg check endpoint statuses:

```js
expect((await request.get('/accounts/health')).body).toEqual(expected)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is using jest? I am having Unrecognized CLI Parameter errors still

Comment: It is, see [jest docs here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#using-with-npm-scripts).

Answer (score 0):

i have the same requirements : change environment
i fond my own solution,
maybe not the best solution,
but it works : [jestjs - how to parametrize test execution from cli in ci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502578/jestjs-how-to-parametrize-test-execution-from-cli-in-ci/59502579#59502579)

Answer (score 0):

The solution from 'Seba Illingworth' above works for me.

There is bunch of data in in 'process'.
I retrieved exact command line with this code, and I can parse from it.

```html
const myproc = process;
const myarg = process.argv;
const myenv = process.env;
const mycmd = myenv['npm_lifecycle_script'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by having different jest config files for each environment, i.e. `jest.config.dev.js`, `jest.config.qa.js` etc.

Then in the config files global variables can be set:

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  globals: {
    __ENV__: "DEV"
  }
};
```

These globals, e.g. `__ENV__`, can then be used in the testing code as desired. The tests for each different environment are then run using `jest -c jest.config.{env}.js`.